# android support library error

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-authentication

Don't know what is happening, I am tried to update my repository and still, i am getting an error of all android studio support library should have an exact version !! please suggest me what I can do so my app don't get stuck in the runtime error and do not get crash !!

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "info.BBBApp.firebase"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4'
   // compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.4.0'
    // compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:9.4.0'
   // compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:9.4.0'
   // compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-databse:9.4.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0'
   // compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.4.0'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: So what exactly is the error you get?

Comment: Change this line `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:0.4.0` with: `com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0` Does it work?

Comment: i am getting red line under compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.2' !!

Comment: what is inside `libs` ?

Comment: @alexmamo i changed what you have suggested but it leads to another error like com.twitter.sdk.android:twitter:2.3.0 failed to load..

Comment: @abhishekaryan sorry but i am not getting what you are saying.

Comment: name and version of jars that is inside your `libs` folder ?

Comment: @SmitShah where are you compiling twitter sdk  ? I am not able to see inside your `build.gradle`

Answer (score 0):

Use latest version so make some changes.

```
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
```

Comment: i am really got frustrated with this, help me out

Comment: as per you recommended i changed my code to like this 


compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-beta4
'compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui:1.2.0'
 testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

Comment: why this `1.0.0-beta‌​4` version

Comment: i am getting error in the first compile file of APPCompat

Comment: wanna know, what is inside your libs folder, jar name and his version ?

Comment: my libs folder is not opening or nothing happen when i click on it.  then i try to open n view it from explorer and there is nothing in the libs folder

Comment: Make sure you've `10.2.0` version of firebase inside `\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\firebase`

Comment: If you've then refresh gradle dependency

Comment: hey buddy, thanks for your help, nothing get works then i  clean all android studio from my laptop with Sdk and did a fresh install, download all the API & all component so now here we are, it is working perfectly fine. :) thank you again for your help.